# remove a character inside a csv file using sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I just can't find my mistake...

I have a csv-file with lines like this:

```
11;1116209173900;8;4690;000;ÖBB;20090831;20100330;O603;603-Deutschlandsberg;
```

I'd like to remove the `O` in front of `603`.
My sed command looks like this:

```
sed 's/\(\(.*;\)\{8\}\)O\(.\{3\}\);/\1\2;/g'
```

but what I get is

```
11;1116209173900;8;4690;000;ÖBB;20090831;20100330;20100330;;603-Deutschlandsberg;
```

Where's my mistake?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a very small change:

```
sed 's/\(\(.*;\)\{8\}\)O\(.\{3\}\);/\1\3;/'
```

You have two levels of parentheses (`\(\(.*;\)\{8\}\)`), i.e. `\2` contains the last match of `.*;`.
Btw.: For performance and unambiguousness reasons I think it's better to use `[^;]*` instead of `.*`:

```
sed 's/\(\([^;]*;\)\{8\}\)O\(.\{3\}\);/\1\3;/'
```

Comment: I see! So each `\(` gets a numbered variable, right? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, each `\(*regexp*\)` will results in a variable/back reference from `\1` to `\9`.

Comment: just because I'm curious: what can you do if you need more than 9 variables?

Comment: @Marcel: I think you would have to split the one substitution into several substitutions. It's possible in `sed` to specify more than one command at once, e.g. using several `-e` options (like: `sed -e 's/text1/replacement1/' -e 's/text2/replacement2/'`) or using the `sed` command `;` (like `sed 's/text1/replacement1/;s/text2/replacement2'`).